# If the sorted rows of a Graph Distance Matrix are identical, what is the name of the graph property?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

Consider the following grid of graphs:
[image: distance]

For the [Small Rhombicosidodecahedral Graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmallRhombicosidodecahedralGraph.html), the {1,4,8,11,12,11,8,4,1} means that for any chosen vertex, there is 1 vertex at distance 0, 4 vertices at distance 1, 8 vertices at distance 2, ..., and 1 vertex at distant 8.

In other words, the sorted rows of the distance matrix are all identical. What is that graph property? As the columns in the above grid illustrates, it's possible for multiple graphs to have the same distance profile.

I'm doing a study of graphs of this type, so I'd like to know what such graphs are called.

EDIT: I found [Coordination sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_sequence). I'm thinking of calling these Coordination graphs or Coordinated graphs.

Comment: I am not sure. However, what may be useful to know is that connected Cayley graphs $G$ have this property and in fact a property that is at least a priori stronger: Between any two vertices $u$ and $v$ in $G$ there is actually a graph automorphism that maps $u$ to $v$.

Comment: I think those are the vertex transitive graphs. There are several stronger properties that have this weaker property. But good to know that Cayley graphs also fit into this.

Comment: Distance-regular? 
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Distance-RegularGraph.html

Comment: DistanceRegular is too strong a property. For example, the 120Cell graph is not distance regular.

Comment: I've seen the simpler term "distance sequence" for what crystallography calls the "coordination sequence". Another thought: every $k$-regular graph with diameter $2$ has this property, and in particular, every $k$-regular $n$-vertex graph with $k \ge \frac n2$ has it. Asymptotically, this should describe almost all examples.